# Need to run aws batch job using python script which will run some query from json file

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, batch-processing, aws-batch

I am doing one R&D this are the following requirements:

1.Unzip the entire db and run delete statements from the json on this db
2.Create a new copy of sqlite db after running delete statement – name it as “{username}_ MVP+Dev_Snowflake_ES.db” example – “adhotre_ MVP+Dev_Snowflake_ES.db”
3. Zip the copy and upload it to s3 bucket
4. Repeat the process for 500 users

The db file itself hosted in s3. I have to download it first.

Sample json file is like this :

```
{
   "user":"buenov",
   "tables":[
      {
         "tableName":"PD2_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1",
         "sqlQuery":"DELETE FROM PD2_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1 WHERE DIM_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT PD2_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.DIM_ID FROM PD2_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1 INNER JOIN PRDMASTER_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1 ON PRDMASTER_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.DIM_ID = PD2_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.DIM_ID LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM M_DATA_SECURITY_FILTERS_HIERARCHY WHERE HIERARCHY_DSCR = 'EMPLOYEE') M_DATA_SECURITY_FILTERS_HIERARCHY_EMPLOYEE ON M_DATA_SECURITY_FILTERS_HIERARCHY_EMPLOYEE.LEVEL_1 = PRDMASTER_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.BUS_EMPLOYEE_CODE LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM M_DATA_SECURITY_FILTERS_HIERARCHY WHERE HIERARCHY_DSCR = 'SALES_AREA') M_DATA_SECURITY_FILTERS_HIERARCHY_SALES_AREA ON M_DATA_SECURITY_FILTERS_HIERARCHY_SALES_AREA.LEVEL_2 = PRDMASTER_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.BUS_DISTRICT_CODE WHERE CAST(PRDMASTER_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.BUS_DISTRICT_CODE AS NVARCHAR(255)) IN ('ESES_DB_INV_00_G03_000_000') AND CAST(PRDMASTER_FACT_ACTIVITY_APPROVED_EMAIL_TERRITORY_AGG1.BUS_EMPLOYEE_CODE AS NVARCHAR(255)) IN ('ES25611413', 'ES25610114', 'ES53130983', 'ES25610542', 'ES25610234', 'ES25611795', 'ES51223355', 'ES25800686', 'ES51319184', 'ES53103475', 'ES25610551'))"
      }]}
```

Full Image of json file:
[image: json file image]

I have written following python script and executed successfully in my local machine
shrinkdb.py :

```
import parsejson
import sqlite3


class ShrinkDB:
    dbInfo={}
    dbCursor = None
    connection =None
    def __init__(self,dbName) -> None:
          self.dbName =dbName
      
    def DbConnection(self):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(self.dbName)
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        return cursor   
    def executequery(self):
        self.dbInfo=parsejson.jsonparseer()
        self.dbCursor=self.DbConnection()
        index=1
        for key in self.dbInfo.keys():
            #print(len(keys))
            print(index)
            value = self.dbInfo[key]
            index +=1
            #selectQuery= 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' + key
            try:
             self.dbCursor.execute(value)
             #print(self.dbCursor.fetchone())
             print("Executed sucessfully")
            except Exception as e:
             print("Exception occured",e)
        print("All query executes succefully")
        self.connection.commit()
        self.connection.close()    
        print("Connection close successfully")
    shrinkdb=ShrinkDB("Snowflake_ES.db").executequery()
```

parsejosn.py :

```
 import json


def genDict(dict,key,value):
    dict[key]=value
    return dict
    
    userName = tableName = sqlQuery = None
    #processData = []
    processDataDict = {}
    def jsonparseer():
        f= open('input.json')
        data=json.load(f)
        userName= data['user']
        print(userName)
        for i in data['tables']:
                tableName=i['tableName']
                sqlQuery=i['sqlQuery']
                #processData=[tableName,sqlQuery]
                processDict=genDict(processDataDict,tableName,sqlQuery)
                #print(processDataDict)
        #print(len(processDict))
                
        return processDataDict
```

I have confusion while making image how can I run this query. If I download the db from s3 file while making image itself and eecute the python script it will not be good one because it is almost 15 gb. Another confusion for 500 user how can I submit job? will it be good choice to use lambda? Automation is needed to submit job and renaming the db. Input db file from s3 and batch output file will be uploaded in s3 also.